# React.js app not getting created [ npx create-react-app ]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-scripts, npx

I have latest version of **kali linux**, when i execute command `npx create-react-app` in terminal it takes approximately 5-15 minutes to install modules & dependenceis.

During this process i checked the folder where its installing modules & dependenceis and there i see a folder named **node_modules** with 1035 items and a **package.json** file only,

but when it reaches near **Typescript** it gets stuck for 15-20 mins and then throws back an error and deletes everything it had installed.

I tried with only `create-react-app` but it's not working. I also tried to Uninstall **nodejs** and install it again but thats also not working.

Below images shows when it's stuck at installing **Typescript**
[image]

And below image shows the **error** which it throws at end.
[image]

Comment: See [ask]. Post text, not picture of text. Try following the instructions. e.g. it tells you where to report the error and it isn't here. It also tells you where you can find a log.

Comment: Also: [Don't run as root](https://superuser.com/questions/218379/why-is-it-bad-to-run-as-root) when you aren't doing system admin.

Comment: i tried without root user also still same error

Comment: i tried to post without images first but it looks like mess it contains loading etc

Comment: "i tried without root user also still same error" — You shouldn't do this as root because it is dangerous, not because it is more likely to work if you don't.

Comment: "i tried to post without images first but it looks like mess it contains loading etc" — Then pay more attention to the formatting instructions around the question editor.

Comment: i know how to format.

Comment: Then it won't look like a mess.

Comment: what i am trying to say is when i copied log from terminal and pasted it here it converted words which are coloured to 
empty  boxes don't know why

Comment: Can you post the contents of the generated log file at `/root/.npm/logs/2021-12-09T11 18 20 356Z-debug.log`?